# How can I get the AS3 array.toString behaviour in C#?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

In AS3, I can get a delimited string representation of an array easily, like this:

```
var Items = ["1", "2", "3"].toString();
```

which gives the output

```
1 , 2 , 3
```

However, I can't do this in C#. If I use `ToString()` on an array, I get:

```
System.String[]
```

So: how can I get the delimited version like in AS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var Items = string.Join(" , ", new[] {"1","2","3"});
```

?

Comment: You probably shouldn't feed the pigeons.  They tend to poop on my car ;)

Comment: @MickyD I think that's disengenous; the question could have been asked more clearly (and I'm about to edit it to show that), but I think it is worth answering

Comment: @MarcGravell +1 for managing to answer this 'unclear' question and being willing to edit the question so it's usefull for people with similar questions in the future.

Comment: I was trying to be somewhat comical about it but oh well. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions

Comment: @MickyD have a look at the question now; IMO it is the same question - but simply asked in a better way

Comment: It's better yes, but it's an interpretation

Comment: @MickyD all communications and interactions are ultimately interpretations :)

Comment: Agreed.  I think what the problem is is that I've seen similar questions like this before and other 100k rep people said to me what I just mentioned.   Sometimes I don't know what rule to follow.      Anyway let me reverse that downvote. :)

Comment: In my opinion, the only thing you do is encourage people to post more low-effort questions so that somebody else can "interpret" them. No offense meant.